# Массивный код для расчёта расстояния от беспилотника до земли

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня терейн разобран на составные части :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как существенно сократить мой код подсчёта расстояния от земли до беспилотника:

```
void HeightToDrone() {

    if(bpla!=null && heightTodrone!=null && tempGamObjParentTerrain!=null) {

        Terrain[] tempTerrain = tempGamObjParentTerrain.GetComponentsInChildren<Terrain>();
        Terrain terrainactive = null;
        for (int t=0;t<tempTerrain.Count();t++) {
            if (bpla.transform.position.x >= tempTerrain[t].GetPosition().x && bpla.transform.position.x <= tempTerrain[t].GetPosition().x + tempTerrain[t].terrainData.size.x
            && bpla.transform.position.z >= tempTerrain[t].GetPosition().z && bpla.transform.position.z <= tempTerrain[t].GetPosition().z + tempTerrain[t].terrainData.size.z)
            {
                terrainactive=tempTerrain[t];
            }
        }
        if (bpla.activeSelf==true&&terrainactive) {
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(bpla.transform.position, new Vector3(bpla.transform.position.x,terrainactive.SampleHeight(bpla.transform.position),bpla.transform.position.z));
            heightTodrone.text = "Высота:"+dist+" м";
        }

    }
}
```

И можно ли сократить приведённые код ?

Comment: У вас получается линейный поиск. Я бы в тело цикла добавил break после найдено.

Comment: @nick_n_a да спасибо

Comment: Если есть возможность составить двоичный поиск, построить двоичное дерево - то результат может быть ещё быстрее. Но врядли это получится. Как другой совет, если это игра (т.е. если погрешность увеличится - то ни на что не повлияет), и у вас 10% или больше результатов if являются верными, то можно схитрить - попробовать перебор сделать через один, или через пять или больше - это может дать как хороший результат так и никакого.

Comment: @nick_n_a Как двоичный поиск сделать ? не совсем понял это вариант. Если пропускать через один или 5 , не получиться такого что в результате проскочит нужный террейн ?

Comment: @nick_n_a что за странный совет про "пропуск" при переборе? Это порушит всю логику.

Comment: Из оптимизаций - большая часть времени расчетов уходит на поиск плитки, над которым находится объекта. Если таких плиток много, то лучше реализовать все через дерево квадрантов (quad tree) и искать нужную плитку через него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А не проще ли рейкастом?

groundLayer - [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) вашего террейн. В инспекторе объекта под именем tag и **layer**. Создайте отдельный layer.

```
float FindHeight (GameObject Dron, int groundLayer) {
    Vector3 DronPos = Dron.transform.position;
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(DronPos, Vector3.down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1 << groundLayer)) {
        return Vector3.Distance(DronPos, Dron.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point));
    } else return 0;
}
```

Comment: поставил условие if(bpla!=null && heightTodrone!=null && bpla.activeSelf==true) (чтоб не считалось когда беспилотник не активен) но вываливает ошибки :error CS0103: The name 'DronPos' does not exist in the current context ... error CS0117: 'Vector3' does not contain a definition for 'downVector' ... error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Raycast' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) и другие не могу понять в чём дело

Comment: В ответе много опечаток например не Raycast , а RaycastHit и не Mathf.infinity а Mathf.Infinity и что такое groundLayer? в вашем коде ... последняя ошибка осталась :error CS0103: The name 'groundLayer' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ещё опечатки не  Physic.Raycast ,а Physics.Raycast и не Vector3.downVector, а Vector3.down

Comment: пришлось переименовать DropPos в bplaPos. Иначе ошибки вываливает

Comment: не считает пока  высоту . Как правильно определить параметр groundLayer?

Comment: Сори за опечатки. Писал прямов в браузере. Поправил.

Comment: В общем у меня получилось наконец то .1 << groundLayer не нужен

Comment: Не обязателен, НО. Тогда рейкаст может уткнуться не в землю, а в любой другой объект имеющий коллайдер... дерево, здание, другой дрон прямо под тем от которого идёт рейкаст.

Comment: не принципиально пока это .